# How can I solve this installation problem?

Tags: grub2

I had Ubuntu, not sure which version and, and it had been in storage and it hadn't been on the internet for some time.

When I put it together and reconnected it, it started up briefly before the power cord was knocked out and the system seemed to crash.

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 to a CD.  On the install, when I finally managed to get past a Grub loading issue -error message 18...I tried to boot from hard drive,and it went to a Ubuntu opening screen that asks for username and password. The user name and password that I was sure was correct doesn't work.

I'm wondering just how to install either the old version that seems to still be there, or possibly install 14.04 from the CD.

Comment: This: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto And this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter your computer's BIOS and configure it to boot from the CD drive first, instead of the hard drive.

You will have to tap a key when you first turn on your computer to access the BIOS.  Depending on your computer model, this key may be different.  (Usually it is the <kbd>Del</kbd> key, the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, etc.

You can search online to learn how to access the BIOS of your computer and how to set the CD drive as the first boot drive.

Make sure your Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD is in the drive, and you will be able to install Ubuntu from it.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I have been into BIOS through the del key, it didnt seem to load but Ill try again and I hope it doesnt ask for a usrname and password...Im at work now but will try once I get home, thanks again!Its how to set the CD drive as the first drive which was the prob i think...